# Check if inherited class has method (and not it's base)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i.e.

```
class A {
    do_something(){ throw Exception("Not implemented") }
}

class B extends A{
   ...
}
```

When checking `typeof B.do_something === 'function'` it gives true because of inheritance. So, how can we check whether `B` has itself defined `do_something` method(function)?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?  Object oriented programming should not have to do this so I'm wondering if you're approaching whatever your real problem is the wrong way.  As it stands now, this seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you describe a problem with your approach to solve some problem, but don't describe the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 no, what you comment is what I typically get to most of my questions. I do the things that are not quite usual. I asked what I exactly needed, and got the answer I needed. thanks anyway for hinting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an built-in "class API" way to do this. But it's simple enough when remembering that classes are just syntactic sugar for JS's prototype system.

Here we have:

```
B.prototype.hasOwnProperty("do_something") // false
A.prototype.hasOwnProperty("do_something") // true
```

And in practice if you have an object which is an instance of the class, you can substitute that for `B.prototype` or `A.prototype` in the above expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) references, this shows its directly defined methods/properties:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(YourClass.prototype)
```